# remove array value after index

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to delete values from array after index ?

```
 var array = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60];
```

I tried like using slice():

```
 var new_array = fruits.slice(2);

 // console.log(new_array ) prints
 [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
```

But i want the output to delete all values in array after index

And expected output of the array is :

```
 [5,10,15]
```

Comment: note that slice and splice are two different things

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `slice(0,3)` to slice out between indexes 0 and 3, obtaining indexes 0,1,2. That's `[5,10,15]`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just want to truncate the array. The simplest way is to set its `length`:

```
array.length = 3;
```

If you were doing that based on an index (say, `index = 2`), you'd add one to get the length, as arrays are 0-based:

```
array.length = index + 1;
```

If you want to get a *copy* a subset of elements as a new array, you would indeed use `slice`:

```
var new_array = array.slice(0, 3);
```

Live example of truncation:

```js
var array = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60];
snippet.log("Before: " + array.join(", "));
array.length = 3;
snippet.log("After: " + array.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Live example of copy:

```js
var array = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60];
snippet.log("array: " + array.join(", "));
var new_array = array.slice(0, 3);
snippet.log("new_array " + new_array.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```